# cannot import function python structure

Tags: python, python-import

I have the folllowing folder structure on my python project:

[image]

As I understand from [this link that explains a python file structure](http://as.ynchrono.us/2007/12/filesystem-structure-of-python-project_21.html) my whole python project will run from the bin/rain_it.py. The code inside this file is the following:

```
from main import main_function
main_function()
```

Where my `main_function` is defined in the main.py file which is defined as follows:

```
from rain_it import hardware_manager

def main_function():
    print("Hello World!")
    cpu_serial = hardware_manager.get_serial_number()
    print(cpu_serial)
```

When I try to run directly from the rain_it.py file, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\rootdirectory\rain_it\bin\rain_it.py", line 6, in <module>
    from main import main_function
  File "C:\rootdirectory\rain_it\rain_it\main.py", line 6, in <module>
    from rain_it import hardware_manager
  File "C:\rootdirectory\rain_it\bin\rain_it.py", line 6, in <module>
    from main import main_function
ImportError: cannot import name 'main_function'
```

However, if I run from the main.py there is no error on the import from the hardware_manager. HOw can I solve this?

Comment: You have a circular import; `main` imports `rain_it` which imports `main`. Try to avoid this; your `rain_it` module has not yet defined the `main_function` when it is importing the `main` module again.

Comment: Is this because the rain_it directory name is duplicated?